# how to read properly a json string in react native

Tags: json, react-native

I sent to asyncStorage all the info as stringify,
i tried to parse it.

this is what i get from console log:

```
"{\"metadata\":{\"lastSignInTime\":1610728860334,\"creationTime\":1610728860334},\"phoneNumber\":null,\"displayName\":null,\"isAnonymous\":false,\"providerData\":[{\"email\":\"ad@ad.com\",\"phoneNumber\":null,\"uid\":\"ad@ad.com\",\"photoURL\":null,\"displayName\":null,\"providerId\":\"password\"}],\"email\":\"ad@ad.com\",\"emailVerified\":false,\"providerId\":\"firebase\",\"photoURL\":null,\"uid\":\"3lkoKoMxQSMKeSxFOyysESt3oKh1\"}"
```

and i need to get email and uid seperate.

how do I get in that object? i tried user.email or user.providerData.email non of them work.

any suggestion?

edited:

here is the object I get from firebase

```
      let res = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
        if (res) {
          console.log( "?", res)
          
            this.setState({ userData: JSON.stringify( res.user) });
            this.storeToken(JSON.stringify(res.user));
```

then I store the token in async:

```
 async storeToken(user) {
      console.log('set user register: ', user)
      try {
         await AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(user));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong", error);
      }
    }
```

and I get the object from above.

```
  const readData = async () => {
    console.log('data === ')
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData')
      let _data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log('data === ', data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you share code block it'll be easy for us.
Here is general answer.
Console log shows its still in string format. I use this separate file to read and write json to AsyncStorage. You can either use this OR match to see your mistake.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
const Api = {
storeData: async function (name, value) {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(name, value);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
},
readData: async function (name) {
    let value = null;
    try {
        value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(name)
        return JSON.parse(value);
    } catch (e) {
        return [];
    }
},
}
export default Api;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to get few parameters, so should I do couple of Asyncstorage.setItem or get the whole object? I edited the post for the code block

Comment: It all depends. You can save and retrieve a json. You can do it once.

Answer (score 0):

after few console log I was able to get it by double parsing the object.

```
 let _data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data));
      console.log('data === ', _data.email)
```

and seem to work.